# map int to 2D array

Tags: arrays, go

**Question**

How do I create a static mapping of an integer to a 2D array in golang?

---

**Current Code**

Note: this is not declared in a function

```golang
var WinTable = map[int][][]int{
    0: []int{[]int{1, 2}, []int{1, 3}, []int{3, 6}, []int{4, 8}},
}
```

> *Error: cannot use []int literal (type []int) as type [][]int in map value*

Answer (score 3):

The map value is not `[]int`, but an `[][]int`:

```
var WinTable = map[int][][]int{
    0: [][]int{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}},
}
```